# Google Sheet: Replace file with the same name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm currently generating a PDF file from an active sheet. Is there a way to overwrite or replace the file in the google drive without putting it to trash? I have this code that I saw online.

```
  if (files.hasNext()) {
    files.next().setTrashed(true);
  }
```

Am I using the code right or there is another way for me to do it?

I used that code on the function below.

```js
function _exportBlob(blob, fileName) {
  
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, "yyyy");
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  var fileName = "FORM137 - " + ss.getRange("REPORT CARD!D12").getValue() + " - ARCS" + date;
 
  var ssID = ss.getId();
 
  var ssFile = DriveApp.getFileById(ssID);
 
  blob = blob.setName(fileName)
  
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents().next();
  var subFolder = parentFolder.getFoldersByName("CARDS").next();
 
  var files = subFolder.getFilesByName(getFilename());
  if (files.hasNext()) {
    files.next().setTrashed(true);
  }
  var pdfFile = subFolder.createFile(blob);
  
  
  if (pdfFile) {
    const htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput('<p>Click to open <a href="' + pdfFile.getUrl() + '" target="_blank">' + fileName + '</a></p>')
    .setWidth(300)
    .setHeight(80)
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Export Successful')
  }
}
```

Here's the getFilename function:

```
function getFilename() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var filename = "FORM137 - " + ss.getRange("REPORT CARD!D12").getValue() + " - ARCS" + date;

    return filename;
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about `getFilename()`?

Comment: @Tanaike I already posted it.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to overwrite `blob` to the existing file of `getFilename()`.

In this case, I would like to propose to use the method of "Files: update" in Drive API.

Before you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

#### From:

```
var files = subFolder.getFilesByName(getFilename());
if (files.hasNext()) {
  files.next().setTrashed(true);
}
var pdfFile = subFolder.createFile(blob);
```

#### To:

```
var files = subFolder.getFilesByName(getFilename());
var pdfFile = files.hasNext() ? DriveApp.getFileById(Drive.Files.update({}, files.next().getId(), blob).id) : subFolder.createFile(blob);
```

- In this modification, when the file of `getFilename()` is not existing, a new file is created.

#### Reference:

- [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update)